# Arabic Support in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, arabic

Please tell me how to add Arabic Support in Blackberry OS 4.3 and 4.5, while i am getting Arabic text from DB in UTF-8 format and when i want to show on OS 4.3(8130) or OS 4.5(8830) Simulator it displays "Small Filled Squares" and on OS 5.0(9700) Simulator that supports Arabic, the Arabic Text displays. So kindly give me solution of it, i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry needs to have the arabic fonts package installed to display arabic text. When downloading the simulator from RIMs website, look for one that has arabic fonts included. For real physical devices, you can install those fonts (and input methods) using the BlackBerry Desktop Manager, e.g. when installing a new (multilanguage) firmware version. I'd assume that users who want to see arabic fonts already have that installed.

If you want to install your own custom font, read this article: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp

Comment: Very Thanks for your quick response, but one thing that i want to ask you that i have to deploy this Application then users who use it must follow the procedure that you have specified earlier that to upgrade software, So is there any solution that changes made at my end and Users just install and run the Application?, kindly reply me.

Comment: Please check the link I added above, it describes how to install and use your own custom font.